# Is there something Limits the CPU usage for a process and its Children

Tags: 12.04, cpu, process

i was wondering about something like CPUlimit to limit the process CPU usage but i am aiming to apply the same percentage of usage for its children processes too automatically without adding them manually in Terminal by hand , so Is there something Limits the CPU usage for a process and its Children ? 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: i dont get what is the relation between  what i am asking about and that question over there i want that when a process starts for example chrome browser when u open a tapped windows u create a child processes and those children dont get limited even if i limit their parent by cpulimit that is what i am talking about i am not in server nor any of those

Comment: cgroups is how you would limit cpu use, the link is a short introduction on how to do what you are wanting.

Comment: ok thank u for answering me and i will continue searching for cgroups abilities if u are sure that it does what i am talking about

Comment: cgroups is the only way I know of, and that I know does not come with a graphical front end. Perhaps someone else might have a better suggestion.